# Debugging isolates

Tags: debugging, dart, dart-isolates

I have failed to debug isolates. I.e. the debugger does not stop on breakpoints in isolates.

I assume that this is not supported at the moment and my question are.

1) Am I right in that debugging isolates are not yet supported?

2) If so, are there any plans in the near future to add support for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known issue. See [here](http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=9585) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=9209).

From what I can see there, it is planned for later milestones, which probably means no fix soon, unless the community manages to convince the team.

Comment: any idea when breakpoints in isolate work? To build server side apps, this is required.

Comment: Now it's fixed on the Dart CLI side. Still not fixed in the browser.